# 'this' and my variables are undefined in my loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, variables

my variables are displaying as undefined when accessed in loop. How can i make define node and 'this' again?

```
for (var i = 0; i < this._m.length; ++i) {
    this._v = this.m[i];
    this._n = this._v.m_Data.cCurrentNode(this.m_C);

    if (this._n && this._n.m_dataele.length) {
        for (var j = 0; j < this._n.m_dataele.length; ++j) {

            var visualObs = this.m_c.m_Con.getV();
            visualObs.forEach(function(visualObjects) {
                var a = visualObjects.getItems();
                area.forEach(function(a) {
                    var uniqueIdFull = a.UniqueId;
                    var uniqueId = uniqueIdFull.substring(0, uniqueIdFull.length-4);
                    if (id === uniqueId) {
                        //*************this._n = undefined && this = undefined
                    }
                });
            });
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this all the code?

Comment: one does not define `this`, one accepts the `this` one is given - I really doubt `node` is undefined where you claim it is - however, `node.data` will be undefined as you've set node to be a string - which has no data property

Comment: please see new code

Comment: The value of *this* within an execution context is set by the call (or with *bind*), so if you don't show the call we don't know what *this* is. The OP appears to be global code, so *this* is the global object (aka *window* in a browser). In any case, the [*forEach*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.foreach) method takes 2 arguments, the second is a *thisArg* that, if not provided, defaults to *undefined*. So if you want the *this* of the calling execution context, pass it as the *thisArg*: `visualObs.forEach(function(visualObjects, this) {...}`.